# How to stop AsyncTask being executed when switching between tabs while retaining previous

Tags: android

Let me explain my problem .. say I have three tabs- FragmentTab1 / FragmentTab2 /FragmentTab3.

Now I have listview in FragmentTab1. Here I load data using AsyncTask on `OnCreateView()`.

Data is loading perfectly. Now when I go for details and again revert back to list view in FragementTab1. Here whole data is loaded again wasting previously loaded data.

Now,here I need a solution which stops executing AsyncTask again and again while on back track retaining whole view and data just like we perform work in deprecated TabHost.

Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Here is my code stuff.

```
public class Talk extends Fragment {
   /** Define global variables over here */
   //private ProgressDialog pDialog;
StaticApiList sal;
TalkModelAll tma;
JSONObject myJasonObject = null;
private ListView lv;
private ArrayList<TalkModelAll> m_ArrayList = null;
//ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
TalkArrayAdapter taa;
Set<String> uniqueValues = new HashSet<String>();
TextView rowTextView = null;

int postid;
String title;
String thumsrc;
String largeimg;
String excert;
String description;
String cat;
String myUrl;
String jsonString;
int mCurCheckPosition;
String check_state = null;
String ccc;
LinearLayout myLinearLayout;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.talk, container, false);

    new TalkAsyncTask().execute();
    /*if(check_state == null){
    new TalkAsyncTask().execute();
    }else{
        new TalkAsyncTask().execute();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Have no null value for reloading fragment", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }*/


    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.talk_ll);
    ll.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.talk_red_bottom));

    Log.d("track", "=================> " +uniqueValues.size());
    myLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.talk_ll_uni);

    return rootView;
}

  private class TalkAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

        /*pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();*/
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        sal = new StaticApiList();
        myUrl = StaticApiList.talk_api;
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(myUrl);

        try {
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            System.out.println("httpResponse");

            InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    inputStreamReader);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String bufferedStrChunk = null;
            while ((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
            }
            jsonString = stringBuilder.toString();
            Log.i("talk_all_json", jsonString);
            return stringBuilder.toString();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
            System.out.println("Exception generates caz of httpResponse :"
                    + cpe);
            cpe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out
                    .println("Second exception generates caz of httpResponse :"
                            + ioe);
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        check_state = jsonString;
        try{
            m_ArrayList = new ArrayList<TalkModelAll>(); 
            if (jsonString.length() > 0) {
                   JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);

                        for(int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            title = jObject.getString("title");
                            thumsrc = jObject.getString("thumsrc");
                            largeimg = jObject.getString("largeimg");
                            excert = jObject.getString("excert");
                            description = jObject.getString("description");
                            cat = jObject.getString("cat");
                            postid = jObject.getInt("postid");
                            /////////// stringArrayList.add(jObject.getString("cat"));


                            uniqueValues.add(jObject.getString("cat"));   // Set unique elements in string array list
                             int a = 0;
                                if(a == 0){
                                    uniqueValues.add("All,");
                                     a = 1;
                                }
                            ccc = uniqueValues.toString();
                            Log.d("unique","========================> " + ccc);

                            Log.d("talklog", "Title -> " + title + " , thumsrc -> " + thumsrc + " , largeimg -> " + largeimg 
                                    + " , excert -> " + excert + " , description -> " + description + " , cat -> " + cat + " , " + "PostId " + postid );
                            Log.d("talklog", "============================= end of " + i + " ===============================");

                            tma = new TalkModelAll();
                            tma.title = title;
                            tma.thumsrc = thumsrc;
                            tma.largeimg = largeimg;
                            tma.excert = excert;
                            tma.description = description;
                            tma.cat = cat;
                            tma.postid = postid;

                            m_ArrayList.add(tma);

                        } 

                        String[] split_unique = ccc.split(",");

                        Arrays.sort(split_unique);

                        for(int i = 0; i < split_unique.length; i++){
                            Log.d("split_unique", "====>><< " + split_unique.length);
                            Log.d("split_unique", "====>><< " + ccc.split(",")[i]);
                        }

                      //  When we need dynamic number of text view's ..
                     final int N = split_unique.length; // total number of textviews to add

                    final TextView[] myTextViews = new TextView[N]; // create an empty array;

                    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                       // create a new textview
                       rowTextView = new TextView(getActivity());

                       // set some properties of rowTextView or something talk_ll_uni
                       rowTextView.setText((split_unique[i].replaceAll("[|?*<\":>+\\[\\]/']", "") + "   ").toUpperCase());
                       rowTextView.setTextColor(getActivity().getResources().getColor(R.color.talk_red_bottom));
                       rowTextView.setTextSize(25);
                       rowTextView.setId(i);
                       // add the textview to the linearlayout
                       myLinearLayout.addView(rowTextView);



                       // saving a reference to the textview for later
                       myTextViews[i] = rowTextView;
                   }


                      //if you want your array
                     /////  String [] stringArray = stringArrayList.toArray(new String[stringArrayList.size()]);


            }

            taa = new TalkArrayAdapter(getActivity(), m_ArrayList);
            lv = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.talk_list);
            lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
            lv.setAdapter(taa);

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    TalkDetail fragment = new TalkDetail();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                    bundle.putString("title", m_ArrayList.get(arg2).title);
                    bundle.putString("largeimg", m_ArrayList.get(arg2).largeimg);
                    bundle.putString("excert", m_ArrayList.get(arg2).excert);
                    bundle.putString("description", m_ArrayList.get(arg2).description);
                    bundle.putString("cat", m_ArrayList.get(arg2).cat);
                    //bundle.putInt("postid", m_ArrayList.get(arg2).postid);

                    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    ((BaseContainerFragment)getParentFragment()).replaceFragment(fragment, true);

                }
            });

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //pDialog.dismiss();

    }

}
```

}

I googled a lot but not able to get exact point. I have also checked that on different methods while using other suggested stuff on StackOverFlow.

Thanks in advance for your cooperation.

Comment: just check one condition the previously loaded data is available or not.if available means don't execute otherwise execute.

Comment: @AndroidHacker I think you want to retain the previously loaded data, because you don't want to execute AsyncTask again to fetch same data. Am i right or your problem is something else.

Comment: @GauravGupta Yes my problem is to stop AsyncTask execution again and again while retaining all previously downloaded data.

Answer (score 2):

For this..first whenever you return back to the `fragment` again you have to check whether the `Asynchtask` already executed or not ..that means check with the loaded data ..if data null you have load data otherwise you no need to call `Asynchtask` againn..

In your fragment maintain one boolean flag..in onPostExecute set it to true..whenever you are moving one tab to another fragment will be removed and again added so in your onCreateView method if boolean flag is false execute asynchtask..ohterwise data is already loaded..

or maintain a one `singleton` class and set your loaded data again moving back to activity gat data from singleton class and if data is null load load it and set to the singleton class..

In your `onDestroy()` method of `fragment` stop the `AsynchTask` like this..

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (applicationLoadTask != null) {
        if (!applicationLoadTask.isCancelled()) {
            applicationLoadTask.cancel(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply .. I tried this but not working. Will be thank full to you if you could be more specific on this. :)

Comment: even though AsynTask is cancelled, It will not stop executing it's back ground work. just it will not call onPOstExecute() and the thing is We can not STOP threads in Java.

Comment: @Gopal .. you are correct .. This still makes data to be downloaded again and again. @ Kalyan Thanks for your great concern on this.

Comment: @kalyan I did that before using a string and saving some default value . I also tried your way but when switching between tabs I am not getting previously downloaded data. Whole list view is blank on getting back. Will try your second way.

Comment: @AndroidHacker From your code you are doing all your code in your onPostExecute only..thats why it is giving blank whenevr data is present you are not calling the asynchtask so onPostExecute not call..so if data is present then get the views and set your data in fragment also..so your data is set to views..

Comment: @ Kalyan Thanks once again. Let me check that first. Will get back to you on this soon.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class that will store the data you just fetched from execution of AsyncTask. In onPostExecute() save the fetched data in this class's object, and in some other method(say A()) show the data from class's object to your views.

When you will navigate between tabs, check if that Object has data, If it has then call A() otherwise re-execute the Async-Task to fetch the data.

This seems more of design issue.

```
// cancelling asynck-task if it is running

 if(yourTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Running){
   yourTask.cancel();
}
```

Similarly you can check for other states of async-task as per your requirement.
Refer : [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.Status.html)

Comment: Thanks for your concern. I think my problem might be placement of AsyncTask and maintaining downloaded for further.