# How to save list and show the same data when user switch back?

Tags: android, json, listview, uisegmentedcontrol

I am using segment controller in my application. if i click on buttons , it will fetch the data from web service and display the data in custom list view. If i go from button1 >button2 then again come back to button1, instead of displaying same list view, it is connecting to server and fetching data again.

Help Me .

Answer (score 1):

This problem has two solution

**1) Either save all the list data in local database & retrieve locally.**

**2) Or store all list data in SharedPreference.**

Hope this concept solves your problem.
Thnx.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19857745/how-to-stop-asynctask-being-executed-when-switching-between-tabs-while-retaining

I am doing same to retrive data from server.So where i should call after saving in share pref?

Comment: You have to call it Where U want to Show the data in your custom List View.